# Outdated processes in ps aux

Tags: ps

Some servers in the cluster have a lot of irrelevant processes in the process list. There are hundreds of them and some of them are about 2 years old.

```
root      9903  0.0  0.0  10752   180 ?        Ss    2019   0:00 bash -c /usr/local/bin/accel-cmd show stat | grep -C3 sessions | grep activ
root      9904  0.0  0.0   6172   148 ?        S     2019   0:00 /usr/local/bin/accel-cmd show stat
root      9905  0.0  0.0   7832   148 ?        S     2019   0:00 grep -C3 sessions
root      9906  0.0  0.0   7832   140 ?        S     2019   0:00 grep active
root      9907  0.0  0.0   5616   104 ?        S     2019   0:00 cut -d  -f4
root     10047  0.0  0.0   4084   112 ?        S     2020   0:00 run-parts /etc/ppp/ip-up.d --arg=ppp955 --arg=none --arg=0 --arg=10.x.x.x -
root     10051  0.0  0.0  17676   212 ?        S     2020   0:00 /bin/bash /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/dump ppp955 none 0 ...
root     10061  0.0  0.0  17676    56 ?        S     2020   0:00 /bin/bash /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/dump ppp955 none 0 ...
root     10063  0.0  0.0   6172   168 ?        S     2020   0:00 accel-cmd show sessions
root     10064  0.0  0.0   6304    32 ?        S     2020   0:00 grep 172.x.x.x
root     10065  0.0  0.0   4116     0 ?        S     2020   0:00 cut -f 2 -d | -s
root     10066  0.0  0.0   4120     0 ?        S     2020   0:00 tr -d
root     10082  0.0  0.0   4084    92 ?        S     2020   0:00 run-parts /etc/ppp/ip-up.d --arg=ppp1062 --arg=none --arg=0 --arg=10.x.x.x
```

I could not find information on similar cases or an explanation for this. This does not seem to affect the performance of the servers, but would still like to fix the problem.

Comment: Looks like stuck cron jobs.  You could `pkill` them, or use `strace` to see what they are waiting on, or look for logfiles associated with them such as /var/log/cron or /var/log/messages.  If it were me, I would just kill them unless this is occurring repeatedly.  It may be worth reading through all your cron jobs to see what they are doing.  Look in /etc/cron.d/ /etc/cron.daily/ etc... and `crontab -l` for root.

Comment: They belong to a VPN and IPoE software named accel-ppp (https://accel-ppp.org/). It could be possible to find out why accel-cmd and the ppp scripts are still running. Perhaps a VPN connection has been up for two years? It has a bug tracker with descriptions in Russian.

Comment: Indeed, `run-parts` points to `cron`.

Comment: It is pointless to kill them, there are a lot of them and they constantly appear. I'll try strace in a few days, thanks!
The processes in the example are indeed executed via cron, but they are not the only ones that freeze. There are scripts that are executed automatically when the client connects, but they also remain in processes, so it doesn't look like an accel-ppp bug or a cron problem. It doesn't matter how long the clients are connected, there is nothing like this on other servers in the processes.